# jQuery Sort Object Array

Tags: jquery, sorting

I know this question has been answered a lot however I can't seem to find a definitive answer for what I need.

I have an object with data that looks like:

```
{Tom: Array, Ant: Array, Ben: Array}
```

I want this sorted so that it looks like:

```
{Ant: Array, Ben: Array, Tom: Array}
```

Is there a convenient jQuery method to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's an object as implied by your language and `{}`, then the keys do not have an order and cannot be sorted. Maybe elaborate what the problem you're trying to solve with a real code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without jquery:

```
var unorderedObj = { Tom: [], Ant: [], Ben: [] };

var keys = Object.keys(unorderedObj);

var sortedKeys = keys.sort(); // [ 'Ant', 'Ben', 'Tom' ]

var sortedObj = {};    

sortedKeys.forEach(function(k) { 
  sortedObj[k] = unorderedObj[k] 
})

console.log(sortedObj); // { Ant: [], Ben: [], Tom: [] }
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Can you explain why the downvote? This answer DOES provide a solution for the OP

Comment: Hmm - so this works
Although (a minor difference) my new sorted results looks like: [{my data..}]
Namely its in an array

Comment: @userMod2: I've done an edit to exactly fit what you need

Comment: Excellent! That works.
@Downvoter, please can you explain the down vote

Answer (score 1):

Javascript object's properties cannot be sorted, unless if you want to create an array/list that contains the properties of that object in a sorted term.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a javascript/jQuery function to sort an object by key:

```
function sortObj(o){// where o is the raw object
    var keys = Object.keys(o);
    var sorted = keys.sort();

     var obj = {}; 
    $.each(sorted, function(i, key) { 
       obj[key] = o[key];  
    }); 
    return obj;
}
```

Use as:

```
var rawobj = {Tom: [], Ant: [], Ben: []};
var sortedobj = sortObj(rawobj);
```

Comment: Downvoter: What the OP wants to do is a valid need programmatically. And if there's a solution that achieves this effectively, I believe its much more useful to everyone, than a silent downvote.